# mysql: query taking forever with no result

Tags: mysql, myisam

This query is against a MyISAM table:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
           WHERE link_id = 1 and counted = 1
```

Now, if I don't pass counted, it gets it really fast. When I pass counted to it, it just takes forever. It is a big table, but I don't see the reason why it should get stuck instead of just showing me an empty table.

Any ideas?

Comment: What columns do you have indexed?

Comment: What indexes (if any) exist on `table`?

Comment: Please post the create statement for your table.

Comment: my bet is column counted is a  varchar field

Comment: @ajreal How would that change things?

Answer (score 1):

Run this to see if you're table has proper indexes. Perhaps counted does not have an index?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE link_id = 1 and counted = 1
```

Comment: this is what i get: id: 1, select type: SIMPLE, table:table, type: ref, possible_keys: IX_2,IX_1,IX_3, key: IX_1, key_len: 4, ref: const, rows: 33333, extra: using where

Answer (score 1):

An index on (link_id, counted) will make that query fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it has to filter `counted=1` through each and every row. Do you have an index set up on `link_id`? If so, you can set one up for `counted`

Comment: But wouldn't it need to iterate through as many rows anyway? (There are no post-query operations.)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are simply missing an index. Try this:

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM <your table name>
```

Do you see `counted` in the `column_name` field?

If not, then you probably want to:

```
CREATE INDEX <nifty index name> ON <your table name> (counted);
```

I would next look to `EXPLAIN` (which Micah explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275563/mysql-query-taking-forever-with-no-result/7275595#7275595)). (I only suggest explain second because my experience is that the majority of the time the problem is simply a missing index if a query is slow.)